# Massive assigning to YII AR model

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I've faced with weird problem(?). Maybe it is documented feature but I coudn't find it.

I have a model class exstended from CActiveRecord. In the model I have method `rules` which defiles validation rules.

I have controller with action `whatever`. In this action I'm trying to assign model attributes with data got from $_POST. Here is simplified code snippet from conroller

```
$model=new SomeModel();

if(isset($_POST['SomeForm']))
{
    $model->attributes=$_POST['SomeForm'];
    if($model->validate())
    {
         $model->save();

    }
}
```

The problem is in following. Using massive assiginig not all fields are being assing. Only fileds wich have validation rules declared in `SomeModel::rules()`. If I'm tring to assign data for field which shouldn't be validated then that field comes empty into database.

Could somebody explain what happens?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare the rest of the variables (which you want to be massively assigned) to be 'safe' in the rules function -

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/